# From numeric string to int array in PHP

Tags: php, string, datetime, datetime-format

I've to extrapolate from a numeric string a date composed by month and year only. 
E.g:
A string like this:

```
201611
```

has to become:

```
2016-11
```

Then, I've to store this date in a fild of db that is a datetime. 
Can you help me, please?
Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php

Comment: thank's, but, in this way, a string like this '201412' become '2014-41'

Comment: Sorry, `$newdate = substr($oldDate, 0, 4) . "-" . substr($oldDate, 4, 2);`

Comment: many many thanks!! It's work!!

Comment: $date = date_create_from_format('Ym', '201611');

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_date = substr_replace($old_date, '-', 4, 0);
```